# How to make rough background with Paint.NET?

Tags: icon, background, paint.net, fill

How to draw an icon with rough background like that:

[image: path]

Is it possible to do this with some fill tool?

Comment: It looks like some kind of "textile" texture at the background over the red gradient.

Comment: I am not familiar with a fill tube or bucket method with Paint.NET. What about finding a png background image on the web and make a layer?

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to make line textures and cloth textures in Paint.NET is to draw many parallel lines and use Fragment. Draw vertical lines and fragment, then overlay horizontal lines on a separate layer and fragment those. Merge the two layers and shrink the texture.

[image: Illustration of Process]

I kept the pattern separate from the white background, then colored the lines and lowered alpha with [Channel Ops plugin](https://forums.getpaint.net/topic/29793-channel-operations/) to get a close approximation to what you have above.